# CSS: Dropdownblox overflows

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, overflow

I've got a CSS problem, where the the text overflows over the dropdown icon (see picture):

[image: Dropdownbox]

How can I fix this?

Browser: IE8

Thanks for your help!
Kind regards

Edit:
HTML:

```
<SELECT id=myId size=1 name=myName>
  <OPTION title=BlablbubbsstrstSt value=42>BlablbubbsstrstSt-System</OPTION>
  ...

</SELECT>
```

[image: CSS]

Comment: where is your relevant code?

Comment: added html and css code

Comment: Increse the width of the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Added a "width" attribute, which solved the problem.